# How do I display a count of how many files I've converted?

Tags: image

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\Umar Iqbal\Desktop\\outputimages'

for image in glob.glob('./*.jpg'):

    img = Image.open(image)
    clean_name = os.path.splitext(image)[0] 
    img.save(f'{directory}{clean_name}.png', 'png')
    print(f'{clean_name} was converted to PNG!')
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I can add a print line at the bottom that says something like - '4 files were converted'.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Adding a tag like ``python`` (I'm assuming this is Python) can help the right people find your question and answer it.

Comment: Corrected code quote

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob()` returns a list, and you can use the built-in function `len()` to get the length of any list. So:

```
file_list = glob.glob('./*.jpg')
for image in file_list:
  img = Image.open(image)
  clean_name = os.path.splitext(image)[0] 
  img.save(f'{directory}{clean_name}.png', 'png')
  print(f'{clean_name} was converted to PNG!')
print(f'{len(file_list)} files were converted')
```